# Create ArcGIS Pro project using Python

Tags: python, arcpy

I am trying to create a scratch ArcGIS Pro project for a piece of software that requires very specific file formats to run. Once its completed I will move the final product to a good location and delete the project.

I know how to perform create geodatabases and folders, but I cannot locate how to create an actual Pro project without doing it by hand and opening up the program. The documentation I have found shows after the project is created.

Comment: Yeah i was able to do it in ArcMap without an issue but now not so much. I was using aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("%s\ArcHydro" %(temporaryProject_Location)) but it wants a current project.

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/arcpy-function-for-creating-a-new-arcgis-project/m-p/1119035#M63021).